# How can I change the URL without reloading the page in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I have a page with the URL as `/tables/123/records/1`. On the page, I have a pair of back/next buttons that fetches a record model. My current controller looks like this:

```
scope.loadNext = function(recordId) {
    $location.url('tables/' + $scope.table.id + '/records/' + recordId);
}
```

This seems to trigger the $routeProvider which ends up resolving the the table model (which I already have). I'd like to do something lighter, like this:

```
scope.loadNext = function(recordId) {
    scope.record = Record.get({ id : recordId });
    update_just_the_url('tables/' + scope.table.id + '/records/' + recordId
}
```

Is this possible in angualrjs?

Comment: not possible if u change the url routeprovider will be invoked

Comment: I will go ahead and allow myself this once to post something whose relevance to the question I am not certain of: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: @Prasanth the history.pushState causes errors when used with angularjs's routing. I can't use it.